# Cache video content from dropbox?

Tags: caching, dropbox, video.js

I'm using videojs to play videos hosted on dropbox. Is there a way to cache that data on the user end or is this not possible? If I go between two videos I have to re-load the entire first one again, which seems like a waste.

In the network console I see this, where the No column is the one for cache, if that helps:[image: cache]

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

1-load the video content into memory using Blob and Object-URL. More info in here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/36772715/1384539

2-use cdn and let it cache the content in a node close to your end user.